# Android send post request to spring boot server

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, android-studio, http

I am trying to send post request from android studio to spring boot server. I did not know how to do that, therefore I  start to research. I found this on stackoverflow;
By the way I am using android studio version 29.

## Android Studio

```
URL url = new URL("http://yoururl.com");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstParam", paramValue1));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secondParam", paramValue2));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("thirdParam", paramValue3));

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getQuery(params));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

conn.connect();
```

Here is the link of it. However it does not work for me.

How can I do that, how can I post a request with data to the spring boot server?
Any help is appreciated.

Thank You..

Comment: Are you getting an error or perhaps exception?

Comment: Use the library Retrofit